# Yii2 validation rules compare model attribute with non related model attribute

Tags: validation, yii2, compare

I have two models, they are not related to each other (let's say A and B). I send them both to the form of model B because I need to make model A visible when I'm creating a new record in model B (so I have to create model B based on informations of model A). Now I have to compare the value of a certain attribute of B with a certain attribute of model A.

Example: I have a model let's say: a `house`. The attribute `width` is for me important, when I'm creating my other model, let's say `window`. Now when I'm trying to define the attribute `width` of my `window`, I would like to compare it with the `width` of the `house` so that it must be smaller. Maybe not the best example, but I hope it makes a little sense.

Is this possible? If yes, I would be grateful for pointing me into the right direction.

Comment: when/where  you need  to campare the two model ? if you can try explain your question with a sample ..

Comment: I believe there isn't a validator in the core validators that fits your needs, so you might need to create your own: [http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#creating-validators](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#creating-validators)

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I have no clue how to begin. How can I access model `house` in model `window`? I have an idea now I'm trying it.

Comment: Why don't you use width, window and other data related to house as the attributes of house model? Why do you want to define all of them as models instead of one model (house) attributes?